# Does "not drinking water" help you sleep better?

Tags: sleep

Recently I had been seeing some websites that suggest not to drink anything before going to bed. One of the reasons is to prevent waking up feeling want to pee. And it disturbs your sleep. But I feel really thirsty at night and I tend to drink a lot.

So, does the "not drinking water" part really help you sleep better?

Comment: Perhaps they mean alcohol?

Comment: @crasic no, they are talking about water.. let me edit it :)

Comment: @jwenting, I am not sure what is the limit. it was ranged from 1-4 hours so far

Comment: So go ahead and drink wine instead.

Answer (score 8):

The answer is, it depends.

You should begin with the common sense fact that the more you drink the more likely you are to pee. So to reverse your question, not drinking water helps you to sleep better *IF* you are not sleeping well because you need to frequently get up and pee.

From the wikipedia article on [Nocturia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nocturia):

> Nocturia (derived from Latin nox,
>   night, and Greek [τα] ούρα, urine),
>   also called nycturia (Greek
>   νυκτουρία), is the need to get up in
>   the night to urinate, thus
>   interrupting sleep. Its occurrence is
>   more frequent in pregnant women and in
>   the elderly. Nocturia could result
>   **simply from too much liquid intake**
>   before going to bed (usually the case
>   in the young), or it could be a
>   symptom of a larger problem, such as
>   sleep apnea, hyperparathyroidism,
>   chronic renal failure, urinary
>   incontinence, bladder infection,
>   interstitial cystitis, diabetes,
>   congestive heart failure, benign
>   prostatic hyperplasia, ureteral pelvic
>   junction obstruction or prostate
>   cancer.

Comment: I bet you are right. But if I don't drink, I will probably get up feeling really thirsty.

Comment: I personally wake up 2-3 times per night because I am so thirsty.

Comment: So, drink enough so that you don't have to wake 2-3 times a night from thirst. This would be about the amount to cause you to wake 2-3 times a night to urinate. Any more than that would be counter-productive... I have been told that urine output increases at night because water that drops lower in the body in the daytime due to gravity then redistributes so that the kidneys can eliminate it when lying flat. This makes a lot of sense. I have trained myself to get up and go back to sleep very easily, because waking 2-3 times a night has been my pattern since as long as I can recall...